# ASP.Net Regular Expression issue for greedy quantifiers

Tags: asp.net, regex, quantifiers

I have asp.net application where string is created in following way.

```
string abc;
abc="vindo|vindo|vind?40|vind?40|vincent van uden|vilm|vilm|slim?new|compas|*|darkc?loud";

Regex ABCRegex = new Regex(abc);

but It throws error.
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanRegex()
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.Parse(String re, RegexOptions op)
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern, RegexOptions options, Boolean useCache).
```

I know the reason is because *, +, ?, {num, num} are "greedy quantifiers"

but is there any way to create RegEx using same string or is it possible to replace these greedy quantifiers with other characters?

I dont want to change my string.

Comment: This has nothing to do with greediness, it's just that you have a quantifier (`*`) that isn't quantifying anything.  If you want to match a literal `*` you need to escape it, as @Aziz demonstrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this string:

```
abc = @"vindo|vindo|vind?40|vind?40|vincent van uden|vilm|vilm|slim?new|compas|\*|darkc?loud";
```

Comment: Just to confirm, I have added `@` and `"\"`. I dont get an exception after I added these two in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `|*` from your regular expression or replace it with `|.*` but it has no sense. Tip: use [Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/) for RegEx debug.